# Create Window with Given Source

Tags: javascript

I can easily open a new window and point it to a URL.  For example in Chrome we can do:

```
var openAtThisLocation = "https://stackoverflow.com";
chrome.windows.create({
        url:openAtThisLocation,
        type:'popup',
});
```

However, I'm struggling to understand how I can do the same thing, but instead give the window content by passing it as a variable (rather than pointing it to a URL).  For example, I want to do something like:

```
var pageSRC = "<b>Some Dumb Page</b>";
chrome.windows.create({
        src:pageSRC,
        type:'popup',
});
```

Comment: At least you can use data URLs:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs